# How many answers can be created using the elementary arithmetic operators?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, special-functions, applications

If I gave you an amount of $n$ numbers, how many anwswer will you be able to create using the [elementary arithmetic operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_%28mathematics%29) ($+, -, \times, /$)?

These are the rules:

- All numbers $\in\mathbb{Q}_{0>}$.
- All numbers are different ($a\neq b \neq c \neq \cdots$).
- All numbers in the answer must be used and can only be used once.
- An operator can be used several times or zero times.
- Use of parentheses is allowed.

Lets's have a look at some examples:

We have 2 numbers called $a$ and $b$;

1. $a + b$ or $b+a$
2. $a-b$
3. $b-a$
4. $b\times a$ or $a\times b$
5. $b/a$
6. $a/b$

Not allowed:

- $a\times a+b$

We have 3 numbers called $a, b$ and $c$;

1. $a+b+c$ or ...
2. $a\times b\times c$ or ...
3. $a-b-c$
4. $(a+b)\times c$
5. $(a/b)/c$
6. etc..

Please edit if necessary!

Comment: I propose a slight change to the problem, asking what is the *most* possible answers you can create from $n$ numbers $a, b, c \ldots$. That way, one need not worry about "coincidences" such as (for $a, b, c, d =   1, 3, 6, 8$) the duplication $(3-1)(8-6) = (3-1)+(8-6)$.

Comment: For this problem we assume that the numbers $a, b, c$ and $d$ have such values that these "coincidences" do not occur and that the answer is always defined.

Comment: A recursive formula: $f(1) = 1$ and $f(n) = 6\binom n 2 f(n - 1)$. You have $\binom n 2$ pairs of elements to pick, and then 6 possible things to do with them. Now, you have $n - 1$ numbers to repeat the process on, giving this formula. I believe this solves to give a closed form of $3^{n - 1}(n - 1)!n!$.

Comment: @Ellyjant There are of course some "unavoidable coincidences", such as $a-(b+c)=(a-b)-c$ or $a/(b/c)=c\times a/b$.

Answer (score 2):

If we ignore all "coincidences", including associativity and commutativity where it applies, we can enumerate all valid exprsssions by

- arranging the $n$ numbers in one of $n!$ orders
- insertingof parentheses among them in [$C(n-1)$](http://oeis.org/A000108)$=\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!n!}$ ways
- inserting operators among the subexpressions in $4^{n-1}$ ways

That gives us a total of $$\tag1\frac{4^{n-1}(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!} $$
expressions.

If one wants to regard commutativity, each occurance of $+$ or $\times$ leads to double-counting, that is: For each $k$, $0\le k\le n-1$, the number $\frac{2^{n-1}(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}{n-1\choose k}$ expressions with $k$ commutative operators should be divided by $2^k$. This give us 
$$\tag2\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{-k}\frac{2^{n-1}(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}{n-1\choose k}&=\frac{2^{n-1}(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}\left(1+\frac12\right)^{n-1}\\&=\frac{3^{n-1}(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}.\end{align}$$
The next goal would be to fully regard associativity. However it doesn't lend itself to simple investigations; one should leave the realm of binary trees and instead consider trees of arbitrary degree with twocoloured edges and I have no idea how to count these efficiently.

Comment: It is clearly invalid to ignore "coincidences" that have to occur, including direct commutativity coincidences and things like $a-b+c = c - b + a$. That is why the definition of the most possible numbers is cleaner than that of "no coincidences." The whole difficulty of the problem is to avoid double-counting provably equal operation orderings.